# Ollydbg - How to find the code of the method OnChange of text field delphi?

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

I have an application programmed with delphi. I want to find the section of code of the function `OnChange` of a text field. How to find it on Ollydbg?

Also, how can I set breakpoint on any window show event and analyze the code of it?

Answer (score 1):

Delphi applications are well known for jump offsets. Since the delphi compiler version is not specified, I will assume it to be Delphi 7.
I have tested the above scenario by making a demo application having `TEdit` and `TMemo` components.([link to source code](https://codeberg.org/k/delphi7snippets/raw/branch/main/OnChange_Event.pas))

For finding the section of code of the function `OnChange` of a text field, you need to search through the `.CODE` section of the file in Ollydbg. Though I would suggest you use a disassembler of your choice as it would make searching and analyzing `.CODE` section easier and faster.

However, if I don't have another choice except Ollydbg, then I would right click on CPU view **Search for** -> **All referenced text strings** and then search for `TForm1` assuming the developer has not changed the default name of `TForm`. Clicking on the occurrence of `TForm1` would take me to `.CODE` section where the predefined text, names of components would reside.

I have attached 2 screenshots for reference:

[image: Ollydbg screenshot]

[image: ida screenshot]

- How to set breakpoint on any window show event:

Right click on Disassembly/CPU view, click on **Search for** -> **All intermodular calls**, you will get the list of windows functions used by the application. Now you can set breakpoints individually or on all the calls of a specific function. for example. If you set a breakpoint on every `SendMessageA` function call then you can trace the method executed when the `TEdit` field is changed.